# Analytical representations for thrust in underexpanded flow (P_e>P_a)

Tags: thrust, nozzle, pressure

I am familiar with the ideal thrust equation:

$F=\dot{m}U_e +(P_e-P_a)A_e$

When $P_a$ is greater than $P_e$, you have thrust losses, and the equation accounts for that. When $P_a=P_e$, you achieve ideal thrust. But what about when $P_e>P_a$? I know that flow seperation can occur and underexpansion happens, but if you plug that into this equation you will get an even greater thrust than at vacuum. Is there an analytical formulation that I can use that models thrust loss at underexpansion as well? For example, how valid is something like this:

$F=\dot{m}U_e -||(P_e-P_a)||A_e$

This way you get pressure losses whenever $P_a\neq P_e$. But obviously I don't know how true this is since I don't know for underexpansion if you can just treat it as if it is underexpanded and the losses rely on the difference between $P_a$ and $P_e$. Any comments or responses are appreciated.

EDIT: Change overexpanded to underexpanded.

Comment: "But what about when Pa>Pe? " Did you get this backwards?

Comment: Woops! I did in fact get it backwards @OrganicMarble

Comment: Thanks for posting the question but It is different in my case. I am considering an engine that can control its exit pressure up to a certain $P_{e,max}$. However, I found that the exit pressure of the engine is quite large and therefore for my use case for the majority of the altitude range it operates in it far exceeds $P_a$.

Comment: So my question is not why under-expanded engines have less than ideal thrust. My question is how I can approximate using an analytical expression the pressure losses due to under-expansion.

Comment: Ok so perhaps here is where I am making an error. I am considering a fixed exit pressure for the engine. The exit velocity equation from my course notes, is not dependent on Pa. So I am still confused as to how using the ideal thrust law will not give a higher value than vacuum of thrust for under-expansion if qVe is the thrust at vacuum.

Comment: But thats what I dont understand. I am not shortening the nozzle. Unless you refer to the geometry of the flow that exits, the nozzle for my case remains entirely the same. Let me give a really simple example. Imagine we have a Merlin engine. We know its thrust at vacuum and exit plane pressure. We want to find out thrust at a certain Pa that is larger than the Pe. Will the ideal thrust law not give a value that larger than the vacuum thrust of the engine?

Comment: Ok now I am getting somewhere. So in order to be able to account for these losses I have to derive the momentum thrust term- this means I cannot just use the vacuum thrust.

Comment: I do not know the nozzle area ratio, but I will try with an estimate. Thank you!

Comment: Oh another issue however is that my thrust varies (liquid engine). How can I determine the relative effective velocity at different thrust levels?
EDIT: Nevermind, that doesn't change anything.